# Hibernate flushing read only transactions

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions

I am having web application which uses spring and hibernate. My application has multiple threads that are concurrently obtaining data from the same table. The entity class which represents the table is versioned (has a @Version annotated field).

The problem is that I often run into OptimisticLock exception (StaleDataObject exceptio) when retrieving data. I understand that this happens when:

1. Thread one retrieves data
2. Thread two retrieves data from same table
3. Thread one flushes data
4. Thread two tries to flush data but it is stale now.

I have tried to mark the transactional getter methods as read-only as the only thing they do is obtain data. I have also set the propagation to ensure that the methods run in separate transactions.

```
 @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS)
```

Unfortunately the version within table is still updated on every retrieval and I am still getting same exception.

Am I missing something? The methods should only retrieve data from DB and they are still causing these exceptions.

It is very odd that application used only by me runs into these sort of problem I thought hibernate would handle it in better way(?).

Comment: What about locking? Do you use Pessimistic or Optimistic locking?

Comment: maybe it is `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT/WRITE`?

Comment: It appears so, but if we don't force increment on write how its gonna detect stale data?

Comment: `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC`(or its synonym `LockModeType.READ`) works enough good as detector of stale data. `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` (or its synonym `LockModeType.WRITE`) may additionaly increment version field every time you read given row, which results in `OptimisticLockException` if someone else has read the record while the other is modyfying it. I don't think you need `LockModeType.WRITE` because if given entity was read, but not modified there's no sense in incrementing its `version` field.

Comment: Would LockModeType.Optimistic increment version when someone actually does a "write" ?

Comment: Also - I am not sutre if Im using @transational annotation from spring how can I change the lockmodetype ?

Comment: `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` **may** increment version everytime entity is retrieved. `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC` would increment only when there is a successful change commit. `@Transactional` annotation has nothing to do with `LockModeType`. I have assumed that you use locking (with forced increment) in the code, aren't you?

Comment: I did not explicitly set the locking with forced increment but I assumed that this is the case as on every transaction the version is updated. (Even if we don't make any changes to db!) The problem is that EVERY transaction in jpa/hibernate is flushed by default. Do we actually need to make a CHANGE to data with LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC to get the version incremented or will it increment version with every flush?


Btw Is there any global setting where I could force spring+hibernate to use LockModeType?

Comment: We try to use spring annotation for read only transactions which forces flush mode to "NEVER/NO_FLUSH" or something like that. This helps, but setting it on every transaction is painful - especially when we get propagation which overrides the READ_ONLY flag. ...